# Change selection on static check button java

Tags: java, button, swt

I have a bit of a problem. I'm trying to compare a string to an array. The array is built up after receiving strings on a serial line.

I use several voids and pass the strings and arrays between them so every thing must be static.

```
// button is set
public static  Button btnRS_1;
// inside Create contense:
            btnRS_1 = new Button(shlSioMiniTest, SWT.TOGGLE);
        btnRS_1.setEnabled(false);
        btnRS_1.setSelection(false);;
        btnRS_1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 10, SWT.NORMAL));
        btnRS_1.setBounds(29, 130, 76, 16);
        btnRS_1.setText("RS232 0");

        if (RStest[0].equals("1")){
          btnRS_1.setSelection(true);
           }
```

I get errors. A lot of them too. And if I comment out the `setSelection` bit and just print out a string to see it works.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.setSelection(Button.java:1047)
    at SioTest.Sio_test.fillChecks(Sio_test.java:604)
    at SioTest.Sio_test.testParameters(Sio_test.java:592)
    at SioTest.Sio_test$ProtocolImpl.onMessage(Sio_test.java:968)
    at SioTest.Sio_test$ProtocolImpl.onReceive(Sio_test.java:946)
    at SioTest.Sio_test$SerialReader.run(Sio_test.java:882)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone advice me on what to do?

Comment: Please read the [SWT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F). The answer to your question can be found there.

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980316/invalid-thread-access-error-with-java-swt) other question...

Comment: I have seen the other thread ( Invalid Thread Access Error with Java SWT ) here but cant say that it helped me much.

Comment: Just wrap the `setSelection` call in the `Display.getDefault().asyncExec` thingy you can see in the answer... You have to wrap every change to the GUI in these calls if they happen from outside the main thread...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a read at the following link : [Invalid access exception](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception?)

Looks like your calling something from outside of the SWT Display thread

Comment: -1 for trying to help someone. And then no comment to say why???? Thank you very much :)

Comment: I agree, a -1 is not necessary, although I already posted two links to other solutions in the comments. You should mark this question as a duplicate instead of posting a duplicate answer.

Comment: Thanks Mick but I cant say I can figure it out by looking and reading the FAQ.

Comment: @KarlNorway Look at the answer to the second link I posted to your question.