# Eclipse ProgressMonitor accessing UI in different thread

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I need to display a progressbar in eclipse rcp app, for long task.
The task is also using GUI components.

```
ProgressMonitorDialog progBar = new ProgressMonitorDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell());

progBar.run(true, false, new IRunnableWithProgress(){ 
  public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) { 
        editor.doTask(monitor);
   } 
});


public void doTask(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
  monitor.beginTask("Progress", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN); 
   theomposite.getValues(); // <- fails here *WRONG THREAD*
```

Because it's not the same thread I am getting

> Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Thread Access Error with Java SWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980316/invalid-thread-access-error-with-java-swt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the display thread from another thread.
Use:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // your stuff
    }
});
```

See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html

You could also use syncExec. In this case, the calling thread will be supsended until the Runnable returns

See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html

Comment: Didn't work, i wrapped the call progBar.run() with it and got same error

Comment: @yuris You can't wrap the runnable in it, just the part that interacts with the UI, e.g. `theomposite.getValues()`.

Comment: @Baz, There is also an issue with returning value from the anonymous class... And using some 
"global" class to hold the values is not a good option

Comment: You can use a uijob and a jobchangelistener

Comment: @yuris If you really need to return something, use a callback.