# Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I get "Invalid thread access" in below code. I am not sure where I have written wrong code. My main intention to write the code is to just display subtask (what is happening behind the scene) so I have added subtask before method called.

```java
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) 
        {
            if((event.keyCode == SWT.CR || event.keyCode == 13 || event.type == SWT.Selection) && btnAdd.isEnabled())
            {
                final PreferencesMO permo = new PreferencesMO();
                permo.updatePreferences();
                permo.updateDocumentNumber();
                final ProjectMO pmo = new ProjectMO();
                final CoverSheetMO csmo = new CoverSheetMO();
                final CommonError cmerror = new CommonError();
                final ParameterConfigurationMO pamo  = new ParameterConfigurationMO();
                final SnippetNew s = new SnippetNew();
                final String projName = txtpname.getText();

                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell).run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {

                                @Override
                                public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
                                        InterruptedException 
                                {
                                    monitor.beginTask("Import Data", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

                                    monitor.subTask("Connecting to databse...");
                                    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
                                    {
                                        s.method1(i);
                                    }
                                    //monitor.worked(1);
                                    try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }

                                    monitor.subTask("Analysing Data...");
                                    try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }


                                    if(!projName.equals(""))
                                    {
                                        monitor.subTask("Updating coversheet ...");
                                        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                                        cmerror.updateCoverSheetStatusforNewProject();

                                        monitor.subTask("Inserting Project ...");
                                        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                                        pmo.addProjectManager(projName,"T");

                                        monitor.subTask("Searching Project ID ...");
                                        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                                        String p_id = pmo.searchprojectID(projName);
                                        permo.insertDocumentNumber(p_id);

                                        monitor.subTask("Inserting data into coversheet ...");
                                        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                                        csmo.insertCoversheet(p_id);

                                        pamo.insertParameterConfiguration(p_id);

                                        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setText("Demo Tool - "+projName);

                                        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                                        AuditLogs view = (AuditLogs) page.findView(AuditLogs.ID);
                                        IEditorPart editorPart = page.getActiveEditor();

                                        StackedLambdaChartInput input = new StackedLambdaChartInput();

                                        AnalysisResult_MetricsChartInput metricsinput = new AnalysisResult_MetricsChartInput();

                                        StackedLambdaChart_HorizantalInput stackedhorizantalinput = new StackedLambdaChart_HorizantalInput();

                                        AnalysisResult_Metrics_HorizantalChartInput metricshorizantalinput = new AnalysisResult_Metrics_HorizantalChartInput();

                                        BarChartInput inpuit = new BarChartInput();

                                        BarChart_HorizantalInput barchart_horizantalinput = new BarChart_HorizantalInput();

                                        AuditLogMO auditlog = new AuditLogMO();

                                        monitor.subTask("Fetching audit logs to display ...");
                                        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) { }

                                        java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> auditlogs = auditlog.searchAuditLog(null,null);
                                        view.table(auditlogs);
                                        try
                                         {
                                            handlerService.executeCommand(AuditLogView.ID, new Event());
                                            handlerService.executeCommand(ErrorLogView.ID, new Event());
                                            handlerService.executeCommand(DesignHierarchyHandler.ID, new Event());
                                            if(myeditor != null)
                                            {
                                                if(myeditor instanceof CoverSheet)
                                                {
                                                    handlerService.executeCommand(CoverSheetHandler.ID, new Event());
                                                }
                                                else if(myeditor instanceof ParameterConfigurations)
                                                {
                                                    handlerService.executeCommand(ParameterConfigurationHandler.ID, new Event());
                                                }
                                            }
                                         } 
                                        catch (ExecutionException | NotDefinedException | NotEnabledException | PartInitException| NotHandledException e1)
                                        {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        Constant con = new Constant();
                                        con.createNewProject();
                                    }
                                    //shell.close();


                                    monitor.done();
                                }
                            });
                        } 
                        catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace and indicate which line in this code it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Thread Access Error with Java SWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980316/invalid-thread-access-error-with-java-swt)

Comment: You are trying to access an SWT widget from a background thread. This is not possible. Like most UI toolkits, SWT is single-threaded and widget must only access from within the UI thread. In your case, read the contents of `txtpname` before the Job is scheduled and store it somewhere accessible from within the Job.

Comment: Greg@ When I run it goes till "Analysing Data...". It throws error at "if(!txtpname.getText().equals(""))" condition. I have already commented where i get error.

Comment: Rüdiger@ I am already reading the content of txtpname before ProgressMonitorDialog called.

Comment: You are accessing txtpname in Event handler thread , wrap your whole progress monitor dialog in `Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable() { } );`

Comment: keeping txtpname in another final variable ,it starts working AND wraping whole progress monitor dialog , it also works. but following to the code i have IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage(); which is getting null. why so ? normally without progress monitor it works.

Comment: You can't access the workbench page in a background thread.

Comment: how to access then ? because i need to access workbench page and then another methods based on execution of page

Answer (score 0):

You can't access UI code in the background thread used for the `IRunnableWithProgress` code.

So you must get the values of controls in the UI thread before you run the progress dialog.

You also can't access things like `IWorkbenchPage` in the background thread. If you want to update UI objects from a non-UI thread, you need to use `Display.asyncExec` or `Display.syncExec` to run the updating code in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Put your progress monitor as below :

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable()
{
   IWorkbenchWindow win = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
   new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell).run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress()        {

                        @Override
                        public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
                                InterruptedException 
                        {
                            monitor.beginTask("Import Data", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

                            monitor.subTask("Connecting to databse...");
                            for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)

}
```

If you want the workbench page, that also has to be called inside a UI thread like above.

Comment: I have wrapped the code in asyncExec however I get null. Please check my code above.

Comment: "PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()" at this line i get null value. I shouldn't get it even i have wrapped the code in asyncExec

Comment: its inside run of progress monitor , workbenchwindow might return null inside that, move it above `new ProgressMonitorDialog...` get workbenchwindow , and use that `win` to call `getActivePage`, `getShell`

Comment: But still i can't access SWT widget like getShell() and other following widgets. asyncExec doesn't work.

Comment: So it seems there is no active page

Comment: Also you need to show stacktrace in order to get a picture.

Comment: But it works well without progress monitor dialog. And there is already page is opened which is active

Comment: Show your code for EventHandler , where is it defined , where is handleEvent called?

Comment: You can see in my code above. "public void handleEvent(Event event)"